# my traceId and spanId don't show in request and response log in webClient log wiretap with spring boot 3 and micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient, micrometer, spring-boot-3

This is my webclient config in Spring Boot Webflux

```
@Bean("tokenExchangeNoTanRequired")
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public WebClient.Builder tokenExchangeNoTanRequiredWebClientBuilder(
@Qualifier("exchangeBearerTokenNoTanRequiredFilter") ExchangeFilterFunction filter) throws SSLException {
return WebClient.builder()
.clientConnector(getClientConnector())
.filter(filter);
}

private ClientHttpConnector getClientConnector() throws SSLException {
return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(getHttpClient());
}

    private HttpClient getHttpClient() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build();
    
        return HttpClient
                .create()
                .secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext))
                .wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.of(this.responseTimeout, MILLIS));
    }

}
```

I want to set every request and response to have a traceId and spanId for log tracing;
I use Spring Boot 3 and Micrometer tracing
but in my elasticSerch log traceId and spanId don't exist.